# UML diagram List object query

Tags: c#, uml

I have been given the following UML diagram to develop classes from to produce a JSON string.

[image]
The only issue I'm having is how to handle the 'reference' class within the 'Transactions' class.

One instance of Transaction contains zero to one instances of a 'Reference' object. One or many instances of the reference object can have zero to one instances of 'PayItem'or 'Employee'. Zero to many instances of Reference can have zero to one instance of 'Department'.

From this should I be setting out my Transaction class to have a List of 'Reference' objects rather than a single instance?:

```
 public List<Reference> Reference {set; get;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope.

Your `Transaction` has 0 or 1 `Reference`s, so it should have a `Reference` property.
Your `Reference` object should have properties for `PayItem`, `Employee` and `Department`. They might or might be null, but this is what the UML shows.

Comment: Noctis, Thanks. What you have stated is what I currently have implemented. Was just looking back over it today and got a little confused over nothing it seems.

Comment: :) Then upvote, mark as answered, wait for other opinions, and be happy that you thought about the right solution yourself :)

Comment: Thanks again, I have marked your answer as correct. Out of interest, can you tell me what the benefits are of the '1 to *' and '0 to *' instances of 'Reference' if there is only ever going to be a maximum of one single instance?

Comment: I'd say that a `department` can exist without needing a reference to point to it, while a `payitem` and an `employee` can't.

Comment: Could the 1..* to the PayItem and Employee and the 0..* of the Department not be substituted for a simple 1 instance of Reference to PayItem and Employee and a 0..1 to Department?

Comment: wouldn't that be understood as having a 1:1 relation between them? where as in the current way, you could have multiple different references all using the same payitem for example ...